# What is the difference between ScaleAbsolute and ScaleToFit?

Tags: itext

What is the difference between the `ScaleAbsolute` and the `ScaleToFit` methods?

ScaleAbsolute

> Scale the image to an absolute width and an absolute height.

ScaleToFit

> Scales the image so that it fits a certain width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScaleAbsolute` fully scales the image to the given dimensions ignoring the aspect ratio of the original image.

`ScaleToFit` scales the image keeping the aspect ratio. Thus, usually only one dimension ends up as the respective given size while the other dimension is smaller.